# Movement propeties in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Im trying to make a simple movement for my ball in unity3d. and im using javascript. I kinda did it but when i move the ball it slides I mean when i press A it moves when I stop pressing goes little bit and stop just like in minecraft when you are walking on the ice.and i want to make it like when i stop pressing it stops immediately, how can i do that? anyway here is my movement code for my ball:

```
    #pragma strict

   var rotationSpeed = 100;

  function Update () 
  { 

    //Handle ball rotation.
    var rotation : float = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed;
    rotation *= Time.deltaTime;
    rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque (Vector3.back * rotation);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually isn't in your code, but instead in Unity's Input system. Open the InputManager (Edit->Project Settings->Input) and increase gravity on your desired Axis (Horizontal in your example) to a higher number, such as 10. You should see the character come to a stop faster.

If you want to see what this is actually doing, add the line Debug.Log(Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")) to your code. The gravity setting is adjusting how quickly your input goes from 1 back to 0.

Comment: Im sorry im really new at unity and i couldnt understand you well.

Comment: No problem. Easy answer is click edit on the top bar -> Project Settings -> Input, choose the Horizontal input on your inspector, and set gravity to 10.

Comment: i did that part but its the same

Comment: You could try putting the gravity up to a value of 100, to make it even more extreme. Make sure you have the horizontal axis selected when setting gravity.

Comment: i dont know if im doing something wrong but here is what i do it.          http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ST0u3XQTZPI&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Says video is private. But looking back at your code I see you are using a rigid body, which employs Unity's physics engine and thus the ball has momentum to it. To stop it in place, you would have to give it an opposite force of where its rolling (probably not easiest). Look into a character controller, which is similar to a rigid body in that it cannot pass through other objects, but it does not carry the momentum component.

Comment: so then do i have to put CharacterController.AddRelativeTorque (Vector3.back * rotation); instead rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque (Vector3.back * rotation); ?

Comment: Add a physics material to your character and change it's friction property to 1